# Magento 2.1: Show available Configurable Product Super Attributes/Configurations on Category Page

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1, category-listing

I want to display all available configurations of my configurable product on `list.phtml` (`app/design/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`) next to the product name.

How do I achieve this?

This is how I can show any attribute but not my "super attributes":

`<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getAttributeName(), 'attribute_code'); ?>`